# How can I retrieve x number of recent, public tweets, either from a specific location or globally?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, twitter

In Twitter API v 1.0. there was this particular API - `GET statuses/public_timeline` - that returned x number of latest public tweets.

However, they seem to have [gotten rid of it](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/public_timeline). I am making an iOS Twitter app that shows the latest tweets from either around the world or from a specific location (Depending on users choice). What can I do to fetch public timelines that meet these criteria?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"There's not really a direct analogue. There's a streaming API called statuses/sample that you could open for a few seconds to kind of get a sudden burst of tweets -- though we don't recommend connecting over cellular networks. The Search API supports searches with geo coordinates."` - Taylor Singletary via Twitter Developer Discussions